# Why has my AWS CloudFront distribution become 'Disabled'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I have a new AWS CloudFront distribution. It was working previously.

However it has become 'Disabled':

[image]

> *I know I can re-enable the distribution by selecting the distribution and clicking 'Enable' - see below. I am not asking about how to enable a distribution.*

[image]

My question is: why did the distribution become 'Disabled'? How can I stop the distribution from being 'disabled' in future, so I don't have to keep 'enabling' it?

Answer (score 1):

Check your CloudTrail (EventHistory) logs to see whether someone made an API call to disable the distribution.

Comment: First thing to check CloudTrail is enabled or not :)

Comment: @JamesDean AWS made a recent change, for new accounts, CloudTrail is enabled by default and the logs are stored in the CloudTrail EventHistory.  See here:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-web-services-extends-cloudtrail-to-all-aws-customers/

Comment: Here's CloudTrail. There's no 'trails' but I do have 'Ebvent History'. The last event is an invalidationEvent - that just sounds like cache invalidation though, I don't see why it would make the distribution disabled. https://imgur.com/a/Vw23b4A Also why does AWS use CloudTrail for CloudFront instead of logging to CloudWatch like other services?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified this in my response.  Checking CloudTrail will let you know if anyone has made an API call to disable the distribution.  If not, CloudWatch should be checked also for any logs related to the distribution being disabled.  Are there any other CloudFront events in the Event History since its creation that may be related?